# Why is TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given when running sql commands

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='root', database='nlidb')
cur = conn.cursor()
stmt = "create table statistics(sno int(5), stat_ticker varchar(10) primary key, marketcap varchar(10), enterprise_value varchar(10), return_on_assets varchar(10), total_cash varchar(10), operating_cash_flow varchar(10), levered_free_cash_flow varchar(10), total_debt varchar(10), current_ratio varchar(10), gross_profit varchar(10), profit_margin varchar(10))"
cur.execute(stmt)
```

I am trying to create a table in my database but it is giving me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/python/NLIDB/nlidb/database.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = mysql.connector.connect('localhost', user='root', password='root', database='nlidb')
  File "G:\python\NLIDB\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\python\NLIDB\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 57, in __init__
    super(MySQLConnection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Can anyone help me out this??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your stack trace doesn't match the code you posted. Your stack trace shows you are passing "localhost" positionally, but your posted code correctly passes it as a kwarg `host='localhost'`

Comment: what is the mistake in my code?

Comment: @Nishitha literally what Jordan said

Comment: @Nishitha what you posted to the question is correct. What you have in your database.py file is not. Compare them.

Comment: database.py file is

import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='root', database='nlidb')
cur = conn.cursor()
stmt = "create table statistics(sno int(5), stat_ticker varchar(10) primary key, marketcap varchar(10), enterprise_value varchar(10), return_on_assets varchar(10), total_cash varchar(10), operating_cash_flow varchar(10), levered_free_cash_flow varchar(10), total_debt varchar(10), current_ratio varchar(10), gross_profit varchar(10), profit_margin varchar(10))"
cur.execute(stmt)

Answer (score 6):

from what I noticed in Error Code

```
    File "G:/python/NLIDB/nlidb/database.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = mysql.connector.connect('localhost', user='root', password='root', 
    database='nlidb')"
```

you lack passing conn = mysql.connector.connect(**host**='localhost',...)

It also **WON'T** work with mysql module, if you just assign values for user, password etc. to variables:

```
    user = 'root'
    password = 'root'
    host = 'localhost'
    database = 'db'
```

and then try to run a line like this:

```
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host, user, password, database)
```

You can, however, first assign values to variables but then write this line:

```
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=database)
```

Hope that helps someone :)

Comment: I was also stuck in this code I just change my code to mysql.connector.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=database) and it worked

Answer (score 1):

you should write a proper connection and then establish a query.

just write in a simple way just like below i have written.

```
import mysql.connector as cn
con=cn.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="root",database="pmec")
```